# Why doesn't short hand decleration work in a for of loop JS

Tags: javascript

```
    const charCount = {}
    for (const char of modString1){
        // if (charCount[char] === undefined)  charCount[char] = 1
        // else charCount[char]++
        charCount[char] = charCount[char]++ || 1
    }
```

So I have this for loop that I am iterating over each character of a string to generate the number of times it repeats. The commented out code works. My understanding `charCount[char] = charCount[char]++ || 1` is the same but the code doesn't work it always returns 1 for every character. I have also tried the ternary operators as well with the same result. Anyone have answer to this quirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user229044 answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654024/13561410), assignments of form `x = x++` are redundant, because we are effectively discarding the increment. This is because a [postfix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#postfix_increment) evaluates to its *old value*.

Your assignment can therefore be rewritten as: `x = x || 1` or in words, if `x` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) set it to 1.
This is not the intended behaviour.

If we refactor your commented out if-statement, we can more easily see a pattern behind it:

```js
if (x === undefined) x = 0;
x++;
```

As you can see, we want to treat the nullish `undefined` as zero, and always increment (upon finding a certain character).

Your **final code** may look like:

```js
x = (x || 0) + 1;
```

Sidenote: Your if-statement only fell back when `x` was `undefined`, but your refactor fell back when `x` was *falsy*, which has broader meaning. This is technically irrelevant since `x` is always either a number or `undefined`. But using the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of the [OR operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) conveys our original intention more clearly: `x = (x ?? 0) + 1`

---

Note that [converting `undefined` to a number results in `NaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#table-tonumber-conversions). Because `NaN` is falsy, the OR operator `||` will replace it with 1 as intended regardless (cite: [user229044's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73653985/13561410#comment130066995_73654024)). Therefore, using a prefix increment works too:

```js
x = ++x || 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that did the trick. Never thought to break it out guess that's what you get for trying go crazy with shorthand

Answer (score 2):

If `x` starts at 0, then `x = x++ || 1` will always set `x` to 1, never allowing it to advance further. This is because the result of `x++` is `x` *before* incrementing, which is `0` on the first invocation, so the `|| 1` kicks in and the entire right-hand side evaluates to `1`.

The second (and every subsequent) time through, `x++ || 1` is always `1`; even though `x++` then sets `x` to 2, you're setting it *back* to `1` when the assignment operator is evaluated (because again, `x++` evaluates to whatever `x` was *before* being incremented).

You need  `x = (x + 1) || 1`.

---

The fundamental problem here is that you're effectively doing `x = x++`. This is a weird and incorrect thing to do. You're taking a simple assignment, and turning it into *two* assignments: `x++` is itself an assignment, it mutates `x`, and you're mixing this with a *second* assignment, which mutates `x` a second time, undoing the first assignment. One of those mutations should not exist. You should typically see `x++` as a statement, or `x = x + 1` as a statement, but not both together, that is almost always incorrect.

Don't use `++` here. It's the wrong place for it, it's not the tool for your job.

Comment: Well then why does the ternary operator not work? `charCount[char] = charCount[char] === undefined ? 1 : charCount[char]++` same result all ones. And my understanding of || is the left is evaluated first and since its no longer undefined the code should move on once it adds 1. charCount is set as an empty object

Comment: @pops64 Because you're doing the exact same thing. Don't use `++` here. It's the `++` that is the problem, not the `||`. The use of `||` is just fine, as I pointed out in my answer, `(x + 1) || 1` is just fine. `x = x++` is a no-op, full-stop.

Comment: Instead of a _postfix_ increment, you can use a [_prefix_ increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#prefix_increment). `++` itself is not the problem, but how you use it.

Comment: @OskarGrosser you're still needlessly producing `x = ++x`. This is at best weird and  a source of future confusion. There is no need for `++` here, whether prefix or postfix. As long as OP's statement starts with `charCount[char] = ...`, then there is no reason for the right-hand side of `=` to mutate `charCount[char]`.

Comment: @OskarGrosser That's not true. `NaN` works just fine with `|| 1`, and it's expected that `undefined + 1` will be evaluated at least once for every index in `charCount`.